# how to call an interactive program and show output immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need to call an interactive program in a process and print its output while the process is running. So far, I'm doing it with this function:

```
def call(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip().encode("utf-8")
        if line == '':
            break
    
        print(line)

    process.wait()
    return process.returncode
```

The problem is, that an interactive program may wait on a user input and does not add a new line after the question, for example:

> Authentication realm: ...> ...
>
> Username:

After "Username:", there is no new line and the program expects a user input, so my code does not show "Username:".

Instead of readline() I'd need some functions like bytesavailable and read(size) but there is no such function as bytesavaiable().

Comment: Use `communicate` instead. It also avoids buffering problems (program getting stuck because pipe is full).

Comment: @Cameron `communicate` only works if you don't need the output until the program terminates (since it only returns after the process completes).

Comment: @Amber: Huh, I could have sworn it was non-blocking, but the docs show you're right :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to capture the output of the program for yourself, or do you just need it to be displayed to the user? If it just needs to be displayed, consider just letting the process write it directly to stdout:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

This neatly avoids the need to hack together your own pass-through solution.

---

If you *do* need to capture the program output, you can just call `.read()` without specifying a size. It'll block until it has some data to read (or until the stream is finished, in which case it'll return an empty string), but it won't necessarily wait until the end of a line to return, unlike `.readline()`.

Comment: thanks! I just need to display it so my version was definitely over-engineered...